# mathematical definition of image of mapping

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

in my mathematics for machine learning book,

for
$f:V->W$ ,

$Im(f) :=f(V) = \{w \in W|\exists{v} \in V : f(v)=w\} $

this is definition of image of linear mapping.

the thing i don't understand is $\exists $notation. From my understanding, all domain should be included so that the definition should be such as $Im(f) :=f(V) = \{w \in W|\forall{v} \in V : f(v)=w\} $, because the image is the scope in codomain transformed from all vector space V, not just parts of V.

would be really apprieciated for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what your formula $Im(f) :=f(V) = \{w \in W|\forall{v} \in V : f(v)=w\}$ says, in plain English:

> $Im(f) := f(V)$ is the set of all elements $w$ in the set $W$ such that the $f$-value of ***every single element of the set $V$*** is equal to $w$.

Okay, let's see if that gives the desired effect by taking an example: $V = \{A,B\}$, $W = \{C,D,E\}$, and $f : V \to W$ defined by $f(A)=C$ and $f(B)=D$.

Let's take $w=C$.

It is certainly true that $f(A)=C$ and so we would expect $C$ to be in $Im(f)$. However, it is *not* true that the $f$-value of ***every single element of the set $V$*** is equal to $C$, because $f(B)=D \ne C$.

What the actual, correct definition of $f(V)$ says, in plain English, is this:

> $Im(f) := f(V)$ is the set of all elements $w$ in the set $W$ such that the $f$-value of ***some element of the set $V$*** is equal to $w$.

This statement is true for $w=C$ because $f(A)=C$, and this statement is true for $w=D$ because $f(B)=D$. But this element is not true for $w=E$. Therefore $Im(f)=\{C,D\}$, which makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

$Im(f) :=f(V) = \{w \in W|\exists{v} \in V : f(v)=w\} $ is the collection of $w \in W$ such that each of these $w$ should correspond to "some" $v\in V$, hence the $\exists$